# Building an HTML Widget to embed paid content - how to secure communication with the backend?

Tags: javascript, django, rest, authentication, widget

I'm creating a widget that shows content when the page visitor pays for it. I'm handling the payment form inside the widget and I'm using Stripe for credit card handling, charges, etc.

My problem is: I want to make it easy for the user to pay for the content, right now, I'm my working proof of concept I only ask for the email, then:

- Check if I already have this email on my system, check with my API server if it has a payment for this product associated and then let the user get to the content.
- If the email is not present in the system, it is created, and return only the Stripe publishable key.
- If the email is present, but it has no payment associated with this product, simply return the Stripe publishable key.
- When the widget gets the Stripe key, then it shows the payment (credit card) form, which is used to get the Stripe token, and this token, along with the email, is sent back to my API server. If everything is Ok, then the widget retrieves the content and shows it to the user.

Now, the question(s): How to secure the communication between the widget and the server, besides using HTTPS? I already have support for application id/secret pairs, how can I use them to to authenticate the requests from the widget to the server? The widget will be inserted in pages on arbitrary domains, so using the `Referer`/`Origin` headers is out of the question.

I don't think that is really important, but if it helps, I'm using Django 1.7 and Django Rest Framework 3.0.5.

Thanks!

Comment: you should use an iframe if this is going to find itself on pages you don't control.

Answer (score 0):

There is an api you can use, called [CoinTent](https://cointent.com/). Its sub-motto is "Purchase individual pieces of content for small prices with one account and one click." HEAD HEAD HEAD HEAD...

Comment: For starters, it's still in beta, and it's not even clear how does it work internally. In any case, my question is about securing and adding authentication to a system that is already working.